# How do I take input along with handling exceptions?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I want to take an integer input from the user. I am using a try-catch exception so that if the input is not an `int` it asks the user for another input. I have written the following code:

```
   while (flag==true) {       
        try {    

            System.out.println("Enter the encryption key!");
            k = input.nextInt();
            flag = false;
        }
        catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println("Please enter integer value!(");


        } 
    }
```

But when an exception occurs the loop keeps on printing

```
"Enter the encryption key!"
"Please enter integer value!"
```

infinitely because the scanner input does not wait to take another input.

How can I tackle with this problem?

Comment: you want to accept an integer value after the exception ??

Comment: I suspect that you are not receiving an `int` at this time.  I'm also assuming that `input` is a `java.util.Scanner`.  If so, call `input.hasNextInt()` before receiving calling `input.nextInt()` to avoid the exception.

Comment: The `while (flag==true)` should just be `while(flag)`. There is no need to check on the boolean value like that.

Comment: Thanks Danny Daglas it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use

> input.nextLine()

because then it waits until you press enter. But then you need to parse it to an int if i remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `next` inside the `catch` clause, this will solve the problem.

See the [docs - `Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> When a scanner throws an `InputMismatchException`, the scanner **will not**
>   pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved
>   or skipped via some other method.

Without having `next` in the `catch` clause, `input.nextInt();` will keep reading the same token, adding `next` will consume that token.

Answer (score 1):

You should go with suggestion of `Maroun Maroun` that looks more *clean* to me.

One other way is to *re-initialize* the `Scanner` in loop.

```
boolean flag = false;
        while (!flag) {       
            try {    
                input = new Scanner(System.in);//Initialize it here
                //....
```